# Using filesort to order by price column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, filesort

I have a query which is a bit more complicated than this one (getting cheapest price) but this represents the performance problem good. So the query cannot change.

I tried creating different indexes for speeding up ordering without luck.

What index is needed to get this 1.4 seconds lasting query quicker? If i remove the ORDER BY the query lasts 0.05 seconds, but i need the ordering.

Query

```
SELECT id AS pid                    
  FROM prices pt                    
  WHERE pt.id = (    
      SELECT pt2.id                        
      FROM prices pt2                          
      WHERE pt2.oid=pt.oid                         
      ORDER BY pt2.price                           
      LIMIT 1
    )
```

Explain

```
1   PRIMARY pt  index   NULL    id_price    12  NULL    9144    Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  pt2 ref oid,oid_price   oid 4   oid 23  Using where; Using filesort
```

Indexes

```
PRIMARY     PRIMARY 9144    id
price       INDEX   703     price
oid         INDEX   397     oid
id_price    INDEX   9144    id,price,oid
oid_price   INDEX   4572    oid,price
```

Comment: See [_Groupwise Max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) for more efficient SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare that a query can't change; without seeing the original, it is hard to say for sure. For example, it looks like you are trying to get a list of id's where those id's are the lowest prices for their "oid".

The query you've given as an example could easily be rewritten to not need a correlated subquery; correlated subqueries are often the source of performance issues.

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM (SELECT oid, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM prices GROUP BY oid) AS mins
INNER JOIN prices AS p ON mins.oid = p.oid AND mins.minPrice = p.price
;
```

An index on (oid, price) would likely be all that was needed to make the above query fast.

*Note: the only difference in the results should be this one can return multiple `id` values for the same `oid` value if there is more than one entry with the least price; instead of effectively randomly picking one of the `id` values with the least price.*

Comment: like i said, the query cannot change. There are multiple prices per oid and also of different types. Also your query outputs different results than the one above. I reduced the problem to the speed issue.

Comment: The problem is that the source of the speed issue could be due to something inherent in the actual query. If the _"bit more complicated than this one"_ involves conditions that use functions on field values, no amount of indexing will help. ...and _"of different types"_ is nowhere reflected in the example you provide, so how could any answer account for that?

Comment: No. I reduced the problem to the query above, which is very slow like i said. So if this could be speed up with a clever index, the original query would also work better.

Comment: The `oid_price` index should be all the query needs; the issue is that the **correlated subquery** gets called separately for every single row in `prices`.

Comment: Your proposed query is not working for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nope, the example you've given can't guarantee consistent results when there is more than one row with least price for an `oid` value, so it's not possible for any answer to be consistent with it.

Comment: The query above works perfectly, its just slow. There can be more than one price per oid, sometimes none, sometimes multiple, and sometimes multiple same priices because they are defined by timespans, which plays no role here.